# create directive in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have a directive, which I would like to use to generate other directives. The following doesn't work:

```
    <span ng-repeat="picker in pickers | filter:{type:'click'}">
      <span picker.name></span>
    </span>
```

How can I use **picker.name** to create more directives inside this ng-repeat?

-- Background

We have a main 'picker service', which injects a couple of services 'picker Local', 'picker Dropbox', 'picker Googledrive'.

```
function pickerService($filter, pickerDropboxService, pickerGoogledriveService, pickerLocalService){
    // list pickers
    this.pickers = [pickerDropboxService, pickerGoogledriveService, pickerLocalService];
}
```

We have a picker directive which basically loops through the pickers and tries to create a custom directive for each of them:

```
        <span ng-repeat="picker in pickers">
          {{picker.name}}
          <span {{picker.name}}></span>
        </span>
```

Each picker (Local, Dropbox, Googledrive) declares a directive, and I would like to use this directive from my main picker directive.

Thanks

Comment: Is that a valid attribute name? It should be picker-name according to the AngularJS convention.  Do you have a directive named pickerName?

Comment: Yes it is a valid attribute name.{{picker.name}} prints the correct directive name, but if I do <span {{picker.name}}></span>, picker.name doesn't get replaced by the correct directive name.

Comment: You can't use scope variables to dynamically form HTML attribute names  as far as I'm aware. Please provide more code to better demonstrate what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Looks like I should take advantage of the directive compile

Comment: Yes, that's the only place where you might make headway. Please update your question or answer it yourself with detail when you modify your approach or find a solution. I'm curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best solution seems to use 'compile' in the directive:

**directive.html:**

```
<span id='pickerButtons'></span>
```

**directive.js:**

```
    'compile': function(element, attributes) {

        var pickerButtons = document.querySelector('#pickerButtons');
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = '';

        for (var i=0,  tot=pickerService.pickers.length; i < tot; i++) {
            if(pickerService.pickers[i].type === 'button'){
                span.innerHTML += '<span><span picker-' + pickerService.pickers[i].name + '></span></span>';
            }
        }

        pickerButtons.appendChild(span);

        var linkFunction = function($scope, element, attributes) {
            $scope['pickFrom'] = function(pickerObject){pickerService.pickFrom(pickerObject);};
            $scope['pickList'] = pickerService.getPickList();
        };

        return linkFunction;
    }
```